# Sin Cos Worded Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

[image]

Stuck at part B.

When I directly substitute (3x) for (x) and let f(x)=8/9(root 6) I get the correct answer which is pi/36.

But arent you supposed to let 3x=z and then sub (z/3) for x into the equation?

I'm a bit confused at when to use direct substitution... can someone explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let $z=3x$, then you're computing $T(z)$ which means you substitute $z$ for $x$ in the expression, not $\frac{z}{3}$.

Comment: dont you re-arrange though...

Comment: for x in terms of z

Comment: No, because you're taking $T(z)$, not $T(z/3)$.

Comment: but how do you get it back in terms of x?do you mind completing it... so i can see what you mean.

Comment: So $T(3x)=\frac{8}{3 \cos (3x)+3 \sin (3x)}$.
If we instead let $z=3x$, then $T(3x)=T(z)=\frac{8}{3 \cos (z)+3 \sin (z)}$.

Comment: and then do we let 8/9 root 6 = t(z)? thats what im confused at..

Comment: Yes, you do that, solve for $z$, and then $x=z/3$.

Comment: thanks i solved it :D .... so you cant immediately replace x.. with z/3... is that correct?

Comment: That's correct.